# Why do linear time varying system exhibit frequency conversion

Tags: simulation, analysis, cadence

I am trying to understand the theory behind spectreRF simulations. Specifically, PSS (periodic steady state) and PAC (periodic AC)
The following concept keeps getting mentioned
"After a PSS analysis, the circuit is linearized about a periodic (time varying) operating point
with frequency conversion effects included."
I understand that after a PSS simulation, a periodic (as opposed to static) operating point of the circuit can be defined in the time domain. So, in the time domain, instead of, for example, the gm of some device being constant, the gm changes periodically.

I also understand the concept of frequency conversion, that a single tone input will be a multiple tone output, and that this is the point of PAC analysis

My question is, how do we get from a periodic operating point to frequency conversion? I specifically want the theory.

If you have Cadence login information here is a link

https://support1.cadence.com/tech-pubs/Docs/spectreRFTheory/spectreRFTheory20.1/spectreRFTheory.pdf

Here is a Screenshot from that guide

[image: Here is a screen shot from that guide],

Comment: Link the document that contains the words and, even better, also add a picture of those words and an explanation of what PSS and PAC stand for.

Comment: The link requires a sign-in. Also, your quoted words "After a PSS analysis..." do not seem to appear in the text picture. You need to be consistent if you want help. Please don't scatter-gun information because that wastes time.

Comment: If gm in a device changes periodically, that device is a mixer. Simple as that.

Comment: So the title is about linear time variable systems that exhibit frequency conversion, the body of the question is about PSS and PAC, and how to get from PoP to frequency conversion, then it gets about gm. Is it just me or is this very confusing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any nonlinear transfer function will produce intermodulation a certain amount of sum and difference frequencies of two different input frequencies.

A single frequency will produce harmonics according to the order of power in the nonlinearity.
e.g.

- BJT and FET current gains produce 2nd harmonics from quadratic effects (Ic vs Vbe).
- Square waves are caused by nonlinear limiting and if perfectly symmetrical produce only odd-order harmonics.

This non-linearity also includes time-varying **gm** or hFE in the transfer function.  e.g. Gilbert Cell multiplier, balanced-diode modulator

- for more examples, consult Wiki.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distortion#Harmonic_distortion
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_intercept_point
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermodulation

Comment: Thanks! Can you include a little bit of the theory/math involved, or point me somewhere to explain it?

Comment: Lookup IMD and 3OI  any harmonic 2nd or +/- difference from 2 sources will come from square law effects of transfer function, 3rd order effects produce 3f and so on  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-order_intercept_point#Single-tone_analysis